# SqlAlchemy TEXT is not defined

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I recently discovered an issue where a query I wanted to run on MS SQL Server was not executing with an error `Textual SQL expression '\n SELECT CONVE...' should be explicitly declared as text('\n SELECT CONVE...')`

This seemed fairly straightforward that I just need to cast the query as text. I've attempted to do this but now always see `exception: name 'TEXT' not found`

I've tried with:
`from sqlalchemy import Text` and

`from sqlalchemy import text` and

`from sqlalchemy import TEXT`

I am using SQL ALchemy `v2.0.6`. My IDE doesnt have any issues with the import. Wondering if anyone has any ideas

Comment: Try: `sqlText = sqlalchemy.sql.text(sqlText)`